# I have an array of timed images that I want to use jQuery to fade between

Tags: jquery, arrays, image, fadein, fadeout

Here is my script, it works as it was intended to but by using jQuery fade-in/fade-out I would also like to fade between the images without too much change to my script.

```
<script language="JAVASCRIPT" type="text/javascript">

var ads = new Array();
    ads[1] = new Image ();
    ads[2] = new Image ();
    ads[3] = new Image ();
    ads[4] = new Image ();

        ads[1].src = "images/fender.jpg" ;
        ads[2].src = "images/gibson.jpg" ;
        ads[3].src = "images/marshall.jpg" ;
        ads[4].src = "images/laney.jpg" ;

var timing = new Array();
    timing[1] = 2500 ;
    timing[2] = 2500 ;
    timing[3] = 2500 ;
    timing[4] = 2500 ;

var sites = new Array();
    sites[1] = "http://www.fender.co.uk";
    sites[2] = "http://www2.gibson.com";
    sites[3] = "http://www.marshallamps.com";
    sites[4] = "http://www.laney.co.uk";

var adnumber = 0;
var totalAds = ads.length - 1;
var timerID = "";

function startBanner (){
    adnumber = 0;
    showAd();
    }   

function showAd() {
    if (document.images){
        if (document.myBanner.complete){
            adnumber++;
            (adnumber > totalAds) ? adnumber=1 : adnumber=adnumber;
            document.myBanner.src = ads[adnumber].src;
            }
            timerID = setTimeout("showAd()",timing[adnumber]);
        }
    }

function goSite(){
    clearTimeout(timerID);
    window.location.href = sites[adnumber];
    }
</script>
```

some guidance would be great, thanks, Finbar

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](http://kaidez.com/tutorial-simple-jquery-fade-in-fade-out/) should guide you through some jQuery basics.

Also the [`$.each()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) will help you iterate through your array without losing your jQ-zen.

Comment: Sorry but your tutorial link seems to be broken, I will look into the $.each() method. thanks for the reply.

Comment: Fixed the typo! Hope it helps!